# Chart.js - Multiple bar Charts - Only Show Last Chart

Tags: django, chart.js

Chart.js - Multiple Bar Charts - Only Show Last Chart.Basically data comes from django and is rendered in the template.Data is proper but only one of 2 charts are being rendered.
I also tried changing *ctx* but it did not worked

HTML Code

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="container" class="col-6">
    <canvas id="indiacanvas"></canvas>
  </div>
<div id="container" class="col-6">
    <canvas id="usacanvas"></canvas>
  </div>
</div>
```

Basically data comes from django and is rendered in the template.Data is proper but only one of 2 charts are being rendered.
I also tried changing *ctx* but it did not worked

Script.js

```
//BAR CHART USD
    var barChartData = {
      labels: [{% for item in listyear1 %}'{{item| date:"Y"}}', {% endfor %}],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: "Total amount",
        backgroundColor: "lightblue",
        borderColor: "blue",
        borderWidth: 1,
        data: [{% for inr in USATOTAL %}'{{inr}}', {% endfor %}],
        },
    {
      label: "Amount Recieved",
      backgroundColor: "lightgreen",
      borderColor: "green",
      borderWidth: 1,
      data: [{% for rinr in RUSDS %} '{{rinr}}', {% endfor %}],
        },
    {
      label: "Amount Left",
        backgroundColor: "pink",
          borderColor: "red",
            borderWidth: 1,
              data: [{% for linr in LUSDS %} '{{linr}}', {% endfor %}],
        },
      ],
    };
    var chartOptions = {
      responsive: true,
      legend: {
        position: "top",
      },
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: "YearWise Summary USD",
      },
      scales: {
        yAxes: [
          {
            ticks: {
              beginAtZero: true,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    };

    window.onload = function () {
      var ctx = document.getElementById("usacanvas").getContext("2d");
      window.myBar = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: "bar",
        data: barChartData,
        options: chartOptions,
      });
    };

// Bar Chart India
var barChartData = {
      labels: [{% for item in listyear %}'{{item| date:"Y"}}', {% endfor %}],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: "Total amount",
        backgroundColor: "lightblue",
        borderColor: "blue",
        borderWidth: 1,
        data: [{% for inr in INDIATOTAL %}'{{inr}}', {% endfor %}],
        },
    {
      label: "Amount Recieved",
        backgroundColor: "lightgreen",
          borderColor: "green",
            borderWidth: 1,
              data: [{% for rinr in RINR %} '{{rinr}}', {% endfor %}],
        },
    {
      label: "Amount Left",
        backgroundColor: "pink",
          borderColor: "red",
            borderWidth: 1,
              data: [{% for linr in LINR %} '{{linr}}', {% endfor %}],
        },
      ],
    };

    var chartOptions = {
      responsive: true,
      legend: {
        position: "top",
      },
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: "YearWise Summary INR",
      },
      scales: {
        yAxes: [
          {
            ticks: {
              beginAtZero: true,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    };

    window.onload = function () {
      var ctx = document.getElementById("indiacanvas").getContext("2d");
      window.myBar = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: "bar",
        data: barChartData,
        options: chartOptions,
      });
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to JavaScripts async nature, ctx might get reassigned. Try using ctx2 as variable name for the second chart.